# impala throws invalid session id

Tags: hive, impala

I am using impala for querying data and my script throws this exception :

`HiveServer2Error: Invalid session id`

Answer (score 4):

We have last experienced this when impala was unresponsive because of stuck long-running queries. I would suggest looking at your running queries.

The resolution for us was either to selectively kill queries or restart impala itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend increasing your connection timeout parameter. Hiveserver2 does not distinguish between invalid session ids and timeouts.

Comment: where to change the timeout parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
raise HiveServer2Error(resp.status.errorMessage)
impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Invalid session id: ####:####
```

the error message above is misleading.

you should make sure your impala session is still open.

before you run cursor.execute, check if your cursor is closed.